# Linq query headache

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

For a project we have had to use existing tables with Entity framework. This resolved in 1 large linq query for the search function. Currently this function takes like 3 seconds for 10 results.

The question is if someone knows points to improve this linq?

This is the linq query:

```
var result = (from o in db.Objects
                                  join omsc in db.Omschrijvingen on o.Omschrijving_Identifier equals omsc.Identifier
                                  join a in db.Adressen on o.Adres_Id equals a.Adres_Id
                                  join oa in db.Object_Abonnement on o.Object_Id equals oa.Object_ID
                                  join oaf in db.Object_Afbeeldingen on o.Object_Id equals oaf.Object_Id
                                  where o.Enabled && oaf.StandaardAfbeelding == true &&
                                        (!iType.Any() || iType.Contains(o.Type_Id)) &&
                                        (iProvince < 1 || a.Provincie_Id == iProvince) &&
                                        (iDepartement < 1 || a.Departement_Id == iDepartement) &&
                                        o.Object_Logs.All(
                                            ol => ol.Log_Type != (int) ApplicationDefinitions.LogTypes.Deleted) &&
                                        (oa.Betaald && oa.Tot >= DateTime.Now) &&
                                        (!kenmerken.Any() ||
                                         db.Object_Kenmerken.Count(
                                             ken =>
                                             kenmerken.Contains(ken.Kenmerk_Id) && ken.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                             ken.Waarde.ToUpper() != "FALSE" && ken.Waarde != "0") == kenmerken.Count()) &&
                                        (search.Length < 1 || omsc.Naam.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||
                                         omsc.Omschrijving.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||
                                         a.Woonplaats.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
                                  select new FullObject
                                             {
                                                 Object_Id = o.Object_Id,
                                                 Adres_Id = a.Adres_Id,
                                                 DepartmentId = a.Departement_Id,
                                                 Department = (a.Departementen != null) ? a.Departementen.Naam : "",
                                                 ProviciesId = a.Provincie_Id,
                                                 Provicie = (a.Provicies != null) ? a.Provicies.Naam : "",
                                                 Contact_Id = o.Contact_Id,
                                                 Naam = omsc.Naam,
                                                 Omschrijving = omsc.Omschrijving,
                                                 Prijs =
                                                     (((db.Prijs_Periode.Where(pp => pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id).Min(
                                                         pp => pp.Prijs_Dag) > 0)
                                                           ? db.Prijs_Periode.Where(pp => pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id).
                                                                 Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Dag)
                                                           : db.Prijs_Periode.Where(pp => pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id).
                                                                 Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Week)) > 0)
                                                         ? (db.Prijs_Periode.Where(pp => pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id).
                                                                Min
                                                                (pp => pp.Prijs_Dag) > 0)
                                                               ? db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                     .Where(
                                                                         pp => pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id)
                                                                     .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Dag)
                                                               : db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                     .Where(
                                                                         pp => pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id)
                                                                     .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Week/7)
                                                         : (db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                .Where(pp => pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id)
                                                                .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Weekend) > 0)
                                                               ? db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                     .Where(
                                                                         pp => pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id)
                                                                     .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Weekend/3)
                                                               : (db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                      .Where(
                                                                          pp => pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id)
                                                                      .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Midweek) > 0)
                                                                     ? db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                           .Where(
                                                                               pp =>
                                                                               pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id)
                                                                           .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Midweek/14)
                                                                     : (db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                            .Where(
                                                                                pp =>
                                                                                pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id)
                                                                            .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Langweekend) >
                                                                        0)
                                                                           ? db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                                 .Where(
                                                                                     pp =>
                                                                                     pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id)
                                                                                 .Min(
                                                                                     pp =>
                                                                                     pp.Prijs_Langweekend)
                                                                           : 0,
                                                 SPrijs = (((db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                 .Where(
                                                                     pp =>
                                                                     pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                     pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                 .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Dag) > 0)
                                                                ? db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                      .Where(
                                                                          pp =>
                                                                          pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                          pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                      .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Dag)
                                                                : db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                      .Where(
                                                                          pp =>
                                                                          pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                          pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                      .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Week)) > 0)
                                                              ? (db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                     .Where(
                                                                         pp =>
                                                                         pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                         pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                     .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Dag) > 0)
                                                                    ? db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                          .Where(
                                                                              pp =>
                                                                              pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                              pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                          .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Dag)
                                                                    : db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                          .Where(
                                                                              pp =>
                                                                              pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                              pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                          .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Week/7)
                                                              : (db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                     .Where(
                                                                         pp =>
                                                                         pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                         pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                     .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Weekend) > 0)
                                                                    ? db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                          .Where(
                                                                              pp =>
                                                                              pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                              pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                          .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Weekend/3)
                                                                    : (db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                           .Where(
                                                                               pp =>
                                                                               pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                               pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                           .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Midweek) > 0)
                                                                          ? db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                                .Where(
                                                                                    pp =>
                                                                                    pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                                    pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                                .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Midweek/14)
                                                                          : (db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                                 .Where(
                                                                                     pp =>
                                                                                     pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                                     pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                                 .Min(pp => pp.Prijs_Langweekend) >
                                                                             0)
                                                                                ? db.Prijs_Periode
                                                                                      .Where(
                                                                                          pp =>
                                                                                          pp.Object_Id == o.Object_Id &&
                                                                                          pp.Aanbieding == false)
                                                                                      .Min(
                                                                                          pp =>
                                                                                          pp.Prijs_Langweekend)
                                                                                : 0,
                                                 Personen =
                                                     (db.Object_Kenmerken.Any(
                                                         iok =>
                                                         iok.Kenmerk_Id == iAantalPersonenId &&
                                                         iok.Object_Id == o.Object_Id))
                                                         ? db.Object_Kenmerken.Where(
                                                             iok =>
                                                             iok.Kenmerk_Id == iAantalPersonenId &&
                                                             iok.Object_Id == o.Object_Id).Select(
                                                                 iok => EntitiesFunctions.ParseInt(iok.Waarde)).
                                                               FirstOrDefault()
                                                         : 0,
                                                 Slaapkamers =
                                                     (db.Object_Kenmerken.Any(
                                                         iok =>
                                                         iok.Kenmerk_Id == iAantalSlaapkamersId &&
                                                         iok.Object_Id == o.Object_Id))
                                                         ? db.Object_Kenmerken.Where(
                                                             iok =>
                                                             iok.Kenmerk_Id == iAantalSlaapkamersId &&
                                                             iok.Object_Id == o.Object_Id).Select(
                                                                 iok => EntitiesFunctions.ParseInt(iok.Waarde)).
                                                               FirstOrDefault()
                                                         : 0,
                                                 UrlKey = omsc.UrlKey,
                                                 Title = omsc.Title,
                                                 Plaats = a.Woonplaats,
                                                 Enabled = o.Enabled,
                                                 GoogleMap_Url = o.GoogleMap_Url,
                                                 InkoopPrijs = o.InkoopPrijs,
                                                 Type_Id = o.Type_Id,
                                                 Website = o.Website,
                                                 Adressen = o.Adressen,
                                                 Thumb = oaf.Tumbnial
                                             }
                                 )
                    .Where(item => (item.Prijs >= minPrice || minPrice == 0) &&
                                   (item.Prijs <= maxPrice || maxPrice == 0) &&
                                   (bOffersOnly == false || item.Prijs < item.SPrijs) &&
                                   (item.Personen >= personen || personen == 0) &&
                                   (item.Slaapkamers == slaapkamers || slaapkamers == 0))
                    .Distinct();
```

**To make more clear:**

We need to get the following object:

```
public class FullObject
        {
            public int Object_Id { get; set; }
            public int? Adres_Id { get; set; }
            public int Contact_Id { get; set; }
            public string Naam { get; set; }
            public string Omschrijving { get; set; }
            public decimal? Prijs { get; set; }
            public decimal? SPrijs { get; set; }
            public int Personen { get; set; }
            public int Slaapkamers { get; set; }
            public string UrlKey { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Plaats { get; set; }
            public int ProviciesId { get; set; }
            public string Provicie { get; set; }
            public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
            public string Department { get; set; }
            public bool Enabled { get; set; }
            public string GoogleMap_Url { get; set; }
            public decimal? InkoopPrijs { get; set; }
            public int Type_Id { get; set; }
            public string Website { get; set; }
            public List<Data.Object_Kenmerken> ItemKenmerken { get; set; }
            public Data.Adressen Adressen { get; set; }
            public string Thumb { get; set; }
        }
```

We have to filter on the following things

```
int[] iType
string search
int[] kenmerken
int iProvince
int iDepartement
decimal minPrice
decimal maxPrice
int personen
int slaapkamers
bool bOffersOnly
```

And this is (a little of) the table structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y0Tf.jpg

We've tried to get everything separately but then we got a total of 12 seconds (and growing) because of the many objects that are in the database and we then need to get them all because of the filtering.

I hope someone thinks this is a challenge and see something I overlooked.

Thanks in advance.

Christiaan

**Because this ticket is closed, my answer:**

Thanks for all the replies.

The best was that one from @Daniel-Hilgarth. To not put the calculations in the query. To fixed that we've chosen to do the calculations in a SQL job that runs every 15 minutes and put the result directly in the Object table.

Next to that we have changed the joins a little bit to the database logic. Thanks to @Micheal-Samteladze.

All this changes give us the following query.

```
var result = (from o in db.Objects
                join omsc in db.Omschrijvingen on o.Omschrijving_Identifier equals omsc.Identifier
                where o.Enabled &&
                    (!iType.Any() || iType.Contains(o.Type_Id)) &&
                    (o.Prijs >= minPrice || minPrice == 0) &&
                    (o.Prijs <= maxPrice || maxPrice == 0) &&
                    (bOffersOnly == false || o.Prijs < o.SPrijs) &&
                    (o.Personen >= personen || personen == 0) &&
                    (o.Kamers == slaapkamers || slaapkamers == 0) &&
                    (iProvince < 1 || o.Adressen.Provincie_Id == iProvince) &&
                    (iDepartement < 1 || o.Adressen.Departement_Id == iDepartement) &&
                    o.Object_Logs.All(ol => ol.Log_Type != (int) ApplicationDefinitions.LogTypes.Deleted) &&
                    o.Object_Abonnement.Any(oa => oa.Betaald && oa.Tot >= DateTime.Now) &&
                    (!kenmerken.Any() || o.Object_Kenmerken.Count(ken => kenmerken.Contains(ken.Kenmerk_Id) && ken.Object_Id == o.Object_Id && ken.Waarde.ToUpper() != "FALSE" && ken.Waarde != "0") == kenmerken.Count()) &&
                    (search.Length < 1 || omsc.Naam.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || omsc.Omschrijving.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || o.Adressen.Woonplaats.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
                select new FullObject
                {
                    Object_Id = o.Object_Id,
                    Adres_Id = o.Adressen.Adres_Id,
                    DepartmentId = o.Adressen.Departement_Id,
                    Department = (o.Adressen.Departementen != null) ? o.Adressen.Departementen.Naam : "",
                    ProviciesId = o.Adressen.Provincie_Id,
                    Provicie = (o.Adressen.Provicies != null) ? o.Adressen.Provicies.Naam : "",
                    Contact_Id = o.Contact_Id,
                    Naam = omsc.Naam,
                    Omschrijving = omsc.Omschrijving,
                    Prijs = o.Prijs ?? 0,
                    SPrijs = o.SPrijs ?? 0,
                    Personen = o.Personen,
                    Slaapkamers = 0,
                    UrlKey = omsc.UrlKey,
                    Title = omsc.Title,
                    Plaats = o.Adressen.Woonplaats,
                    Enabled = o.Enabled,
                    GoogleMap_Url = o.GoogleMap_Url,
                    InkoopPrijs = o.InkoopPrijs,
                    Type_Id = o.Type_Id,
                    Website = o.Website,
                    Adressen = o.Adressen,
                    Thumb = o.Object_Afbeeldingen.FirstOrDefault(af => af.StandaardAfbeelding).Tumbnial
                }
            ) 
.Distinct();
```

This takes around 1 and a half second to give the first 10 result where the old one toke a minimum of 3.

But i'm still open for suggestions.

Thanks

Christiaan

Comment: HOLY.
LIVING.
CRAP!

Comment: Yeah that was mine reaction too when i needed too speed this up.

Comment: There isn't really much we can do here. The problem is that this query simply tries to do too much. But without knowing what it actually is supposed to do, it is hard to optimize it. **Honestly, this query is a single big fail.** It is unmaintainable to the extreme. However, one thing: There are so unbelievable many sub queries in there that I wonder whether it would make sense to fetch some of those tables completely and do some of those operations in memory.

Comment: I will try to post more information about the tables and what the query should do.

Comment: It seems that this query contains a complete algorithm for calculating the price (`Prijs = ...`). In the worst case, it queries the table `Prijs_Periode` ***24*** times - per object! Fixing this might already bring your performance into an acceptable region.

Comment: Take a print screen of the query, post it on the The Dayly WTF, shift-delete it, get a person that understands the business requirements, and start over from scratch. This has sailed past the point of zero maintainability.

Comment: If only stored procedures weren't so unfashionable these days...

Comment: Thanks for all the reactions.
Taking the price queries away makes the query 1 to 1.2 second faster. So i will check for another solution for that.

Comment: This isn't a query, this is a monster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've reviewed your query I could figure out that you are querying the database objects int your query.

It will be much more faster if you push your logic in database and get the result in LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it doesn't make a difference in the loading time if i do it with joins or with the database logic.But it makes it a little bit better readable.

Comment: There are two things that I can consider:

1) You can do your SQL Query better or do Database optimization

2) There is no other way to improve query execution time